# CSS: Can I set all the text properties in one declaration?

Tags: css

When working with CSS, i'm able to set all properties of font in one declaration like 
`font: italic bold 24px "verdana";` instead of writing `font-style:italic; font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; font-family:"verdana";`

Similarly i tried to set text properties (`text-align, text-indent, text-transform, text-decoration`, etc) in one declaration but i did not get the effects.

What I want to know is...

  Is it possible to set these kind of properties in one declaration like `text:underline justify capitalize 20px;`?
  
if possible..., 

-what properties can I set?

-What is the order of the properties that i should specify?

-what are the required properties?

Comment: I'll bet you can do this with `LESS`.

Answer (score 2):

Although `font` is a known abbreviation for an aggregate collection of properties, there does not appear to be any equivalent to let you specify all text properties together.

Comment: ["shorthand properties"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) is the term.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible and neither efficient to look back on. But what you can do is make an extra stylesheet.css and add "standard" classes in there like a class: **text1** 
Which you will fill in with:

`text-align: justify;
text-decoration: underline;`

etc.

so you just have basic classes which add alot of css you dont need to make an extra stylesheet but it would keep everything orderd from custom css to standard classes you made on your own and you can use em for sites in the future.

Comment: You can do this with all kind of css styles like it safes me alot of time if i want something `font-size: 10px; color: red; text-decoration: none;` ill just add the class 'font10rednone' to my text and i dont have to fill in the css again working this way for so long now and never regretted it ;)